# Equation for a path of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Take a matrix ($2\times 2$) path $A(t)$ for $t\in [0,T]$ s.t. the equation $det(A(t)-\mathbb{I})=0$ has solutions for $t=0, 1,..., \lfloor \lambda T/2\pi \rfloor$, for $\lambda$ a positive real constant. Suppose now you have a fixed rotation matrix $R_{\theta}$. What can be said about the solutions of $det(BA(t)-\mathbb{I})=0$? How many are there? For what time $t$ they happen? How much does the choice of $\theta$ influences this problem?

If we set $A(t)$ to be
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}(t) & a_{21}(t)\\
a_{12}(t) & a_{22}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
and $R_{\theta}$ to be
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta &  \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
we get that the first equation reads
$$\det A(t)-a_{11}(t)-a_{22}(t)+1=0$$
while the second one reads
$$\det A(t)-(a_{11}(t)+a_{22}(t))\cos\theta +(a_{12}(t)-a_{21}(t))\sin\theta +1=0$$
I have tried to produce solutions to the second equation from solutions of the first one, but haven't been succesful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears there's no relationship, i.e., we need the entries of $A(t)$, not just $\theta$. For instance, if $A(t)$ is rotation by $2\pi t$, the roots are shifted by $\theta$, while if $A(t) = \cos(2\pi t)I$, there are no solutions for $\theta \neq 0$. Analogously, we might have a curve in the plane that passes through $(1, 0)$ at regular times; if we rotate the curve by $\theta$ about the origin, we have no general information on whether the rotated curve passes through $(1, 0)$, and if so, when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path in the space of matrices may be identified with an ordered pair of paths in the real plane; in row-column notation for double indices, we might write
$$
x_{1}(t) = (a_{11}(t), a_{21}(t))
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  a_{11}(t) \\
  a_{21}(t) \\
  \end{array}\right],\qquad
x_{2}(t) = (a_{12}(t), a_{22}(t))
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  a_{12}(t) \\
  a_{22}(t) \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$
Left multiplication by the $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix $R_{\theta}$ amounts to rotating each path counterclockwise about the origin by $\theta$.

The condition $\det(A(t) - I) = 0$ holds if $x_{1}(t) = (1, 0)$ or $x_{2}(t) = (0, 1)$ (because one column or the other of $A$ is zero), and may or may not hold otherwise (depending on the column functions).

As noted in the comments, there is no general ($\theta$-dependent, $A$-independent) relationship between the solutions of $\det(A(t) - I) = 0$ and the solutions of $\det(BA(t) - I) = 0$, compare
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
    \cos(2\pi t) & -\sin(2\pi t) \\
    \sin(2\pi t) &  \cos(2\pi t) \\
  \end{array}\right],\qquad
A = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    \cos(2\pi t) & 0 \\
    0 &  \cos(2\pi t) \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$